# Do we know how much alcohol Vikings drank?

Tags: vikings, alcohol

We know the drink of choice, at least for early Vikings, was mead. But do we know exactly how much alcohol the Vikings drank?

Was there a significant supply of alcohol so that each man could drink as much as they liked or was there an element of rationing involved?

Comment: With the exception of voyages, alcoholic drinks are pretty cheap to produce...I've never heard of cultures of that era where alcoholic beverages were hard to find, but many descriptions of what we'd call binge drinking today.

Comment: The consumption was most likely significant. Alcohol was a good way to increase water quality.

Answer (score -2):

Scandanavian climate did not support the growth of grapes, Grapes grow well in warm, dry climates like Spain, Italy, France.

But Beers made from wheat which did grow, and honey distilled into "Mead" was a common drink among Viking. The Vikings did drink daily, as many nomadic cultures did. However this was not because they enjoyed being wasted. When clean drinking water was not available, beer and ale offered a viable source of hydration, often beers were very low alcohol content to wash down a meal or drink on long voyages.

Comment: Mead isn't made by distilling but by fermenting honey (usually diluted, which is just as well as gathering enough honey would take a lot of labour)